# Google Map not loading in container

Tags: asp.net, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load Google Map in a `<td>`, but I am unable to find the issue.

**SCRIPT**

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33, 73),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

}
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" id="map" style="height:600px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

You can see in the following image that how my map is loading, it should be loaded in that light gray area.
[image]

Comment: Try loading it into a `div` instead of a `td` or a `table`.

Comment: What defines the width of the cell?

Comment: I checked it with width:auto and width:500px. its giving same result.

Comment: If you're using tables for layout purposes then unless it's actual tabular data then you're doing it wrong. Use div, header, footer, section, nav, article, span, aside etc instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Billy, but can you tell me why it's not good to use table for layout purpose? I am a little weak in designing that is why I am using tables. Also is there any tool in visual studios asp.net for layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a div inside td

```
<td colspan="6" style="height:600px;">
        <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>         
</td>
```